# How to access to custom Vue props inside asyncData in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have custom function in my project which used as plugin

```
import Vue from 'vue'

function copyText(text) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('value', text);
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    var result = document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
    return result;
}

Vue.prototype.$copyText = (text) => copyText(text);
```

How I can access to this vue prop inside `asyncData`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't access *this* in asyncData as stated in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/). However you could try to call the copy method in the mounted hook like this:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$copyText("some text");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You **don't** have access to the component instance through `this` inside `asyncData` because it is called **before initiating** the component.

Source: https://nuxtjs.org/api/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inject` in a `plugin` to get it in the `asyncData` instead the Vue prototype.

For example, in your plugin do this:

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('copyText', (text) => {
    const input = document.createElement('input')
    input.setAttribute('value', text)
    document.body.appendChild(input)
    input.select()
    const result = document.execCommand('copy')
    document.body.removeChild(input)
    return result
  })
}
```

and in the `asyncData` you can get it:

```
asyncDate({$http, $copyText}) {
  $copyText('text')
}
```

or in other place:

```
created() {
  this.$copyText('text')
}
```